# Parsing the COR_PRF_FUNCTION_ARGUMENT_INFO Structure

Tags: .net, clr, clr-profiling-api, clrprofiler

I'm wondering how I should go about parsing the **COR_PRF_FUNCTION_ARGUMENT_INFO** structure that is supplied to the callback method of the **SetEnterLeaveFunctionHooks3WithInfo** function.

From my understand the structure contains a group of memory addresses which contain the locations of the function parameter values. The info regarding this structure can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/unmanaged-api/profiling/cor-prf-function-argument-info-structure

I've also parsed the function's metadata to determine the number of parameters supplied to the function and each parameter's type. I used the **GetMethodProps** function of the **IMetaDataImport** interface.

I'm stuck on what to do next and how would I would proceed to get the actual value of each parameter using the **COR_PRF_FUNCTION_ARGUMENT_INFO** structure? Do I need to determine the size of each parameter to calculate an offset from a memory address for each parameter?
Thanks for any help

Comment: It's a variable sized array, with the size stored in `numRanges`. Each parameter contains a pointer and a size, see [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/unmanaged-api/profiling/cor-prf-function-argument-range-structure). What code do you have currently to get your callback in place?

Comment: @Charlieface Thanks for the response. I understand how the structure is built, sorry if that caused some confusion. But let's say at ranges[0].startAddress, how do I know how many bytes at that address to read for each parameter?

Comment: I suppose you need to know what the parameter types are anyway, not sure where you get that info from

Comment: @Charlieface I do have the parameter types as well. I just need to figure out the size of each parameter type then? Not sure how I would do that.

Comment: `sizeof`? Are you working in C# or C++?

Comment: @Charlieface, it would have to be C++, managed profiler callbacks are not permitted to re-enter managed code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to work out the size of each argument and how to interpret it based on the type of the argument:

- If its a primitive value type, then the size and representation should be fairly self-evident. (int => '4 byte integer', double => '8 byte floating point', bool => '4 byte integer where 0 is false and everything else is true', IntPtr => 'pointer-sized integer')
- If its a reference type, then it will be a pointer-sized ObjectID. (warning: ObjectIDs are subject to changing between callbacks, so don't try to hang onto them unless you also hook the GC callbacks and update them when the objects move).
- If its a value type, then you should be able to use [GetClassLayout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/unmanaged-api/profiling/icorprofilerinfo2-getclasslayout-method) to get the size of the value and the location of the fields within it.
- If its passed by reference, then it will be a (pointer-sized) pointer to the memory location where the actual value is stored (or will be stored in the case of out arguments).